# Bernstein von Mises Theorem for Linear Regression

Tags: bayesian, references, linear

I want to know what conditions are needed and how those conditions can be verified for Bernstein von Mises in linear regression setting with finite dimensions.

I have tried several textbooks but not have been able to find the exact example of linear regression with finite dimensions. I don't have strong statistical background so I have difficulty applying BvM directly to the example myself.

Can anyone recommend some references? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a paper in the Annals of Statistics (2011).  You can find the paper "[Bernstein von Mises Theorems for Gaussian Regression with increasing number of regressors](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.1370.pdf)" by Dominique Bontemps.  The paper deals with the asymptotic normality of the posterior distribution for Gaussian linear regression parameters as the number of regressors increases.